# How can I specify a guard in middleware for route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, jwt

I have two routes as follow:

```
Route::GET('admins/', 'UserController@index')->middleware('jwt.auth');
Route::GET('visitors', 'UserController@indexVisitors')->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

And I have guards in **auth.php**:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt-auth',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'visitor_api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt-auth',
        'provider' => 'visitors',
    ],
],
```

I tried to specify the guard in the middleware but it doesn't work.

```
Route::GET('visitors', 'UserController@indexVisitors')
->middleware('jwt.auth.visitors_api');
```

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to set a default guard through out the `Route::group` then you can use below syntax

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth:visitor_api'], 'prefix' => 'visitor'], function() {
  Route::get('/home', 'VisitorController@index')->name('home');
  Route::get('/list', 'VisitorController@list')->name('list'); 
});
```

after this you can use `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth::guard('visitor_api')->id()` in your VisitorController.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want

```
Route::GET('visitors', 'UserController@indexVisitors')->middleware('auth:visitors_api');
```

You can specify a guard by passing it as a parameter (after the colon character)

You can refer to the laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Under Authentication Quickstart > Protecting Routes > Specifying A Guard

Comment: Thanks for the answer. with the above line it says: guard [visitors_api] not defined and replacing with `jwt.auth:visitors_api` says: `User not found' because it tries the defaul guard not the `visitors_api`

Comment: I don't know anything about `jwt.auth` middleware. Did you install `jwt` package? Or did you make your own middleware?

Comment: Can you provide me the link to the package

Comment: The `jwt.auth:visitors_api` is working, but it works also with another user token.